# How to work with image in ASP.net 5?

Tags: dnx, asp.net-core, dnx50

i need resize image, i am use ASP.net 5, and i want to host my app on ubuntu. I have a problem, with dnxcore50, it is not supported system.drawing and other custom libs. How to resolve this problem or what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Scott Hanselman [wrote about this on his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RFCServersideImageAndGraphicsProcessingWithNETCoreAndASPNET5.aspx) - it sounds like there are not a lot of good options right now.